# SMTP connect() failed. outlook365

Tags: wordpress, smtp

Busquei em outros topicos similares e nenhum resolveu.

Digamos que de um dia para o outro simplesmente todos os emails do site parou de funcionar, e agora está dando problema em conectar com o servidor.

Olhem as configurações e o log de erro:

```
    Versions:
WordPress: 4.9.6
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 5.6.32
WP Mail SMTP: 1.2.5

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Host: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
SMTPSecure: tls
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(true)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)

Server:
OpenSSL: Yes
Apache.mod_security: No
SMTP Debug:
2018-06-21 13:37:19 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array (
)
2018-06-21 13:37:19 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
2018-06-21 13:37:19 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
2018-06-21 13:37:19 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
2018-06-21 13:37:19 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Please copy only the content of the error debug message above, identified with an orange left border, into the support forum topic if you experienc
```

Ja tentei outras portas como por exemplo 25 
e mesmo assim continua dando erro.

Comment: Consegue investigar se o servidor que o seu serviço se encontra tem rota para `smtp.office365.com`? Um ping deve dizer se tem rota

Comment: Investigue nas configurações do outlook365, provavelmente exista alguma configuração para permitir que sei e-mail seja sender.

Comment: @AlisonRamosdaSilva o problema que  testei outros SMTP e eles tambem não funcionaram , estou começando achar que a locaweb bloquearam alguma porta e ficou sem rota, por que no dia anterior a esse problema me informaram aqui que deu um erro no banco de dados.

Comment: Bom agora Consegui conectar direto, DNS da local web não estava permitindo ai forcei o SMTP do outlook, o problema agora é que o contact form 7 não está conseguindo mandar email.